# what is the fast and the easiest way to change the order of divs in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to move div1 and div2 to the end of list

> with only **vanilla javascript**

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="chlid-1"></div>
   <div id="chlid-2"></div>
   <div id="chlid-3"></div>
   <div id="chlid-4"></div>
   <div id="chlid-5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do it with javascript!

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS flex on a parent, and the [**order** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) on the desired child elements

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#child-1,
#child-2 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="child-1">1</div>
   <div id="child-2">2</div>
   <div id="child-3">3</div>
   <div id="child-4">4</div>
   <div id="child-5">5</div>
</div>
```

Using JavaScript - use the [Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) method like:

```js
// DOM utils:

const ELS = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);


// Task:

EL(".container").append(...ELS("#child-1, #child-2"));
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="child-1">1</div>
   <div id="child-2">2</div>
   <div id="child-3">3</div>
   <div id="child-4">4</div>
   <div id="child-5">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following and the old div will be removed automatically

```
var element = document.getElementById('child1');
var parent = element.parentNode;
parent.insertAfter(element, parent.lastChild);
```